# connecting sql developer with remote oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have access to oracle database server. I wanted to connect it with sql developer. I have certain username /password for the remote server. and within that server I have access to database with certain username/ password.

I access to that database form server using sql plus with command `sqlplus abcd@xe` and i have access to that database.

Whenever I tried to connect it with sql developer, connection is not established.

I tired as :

```
connection name: test
username: username to the remote server
password: password to remote server.

hostname: server host name
port :1521
sid : xe
```

how can I connect to remote database located in remote server?

Comment: Maybe port 1521 is not open on the host machine.

Comment: Whats the error message did you get during the connection?

Comment: What is the `tnsnames.ora` entry for the XE TNS alias you used from SQL\*Plus? Are you using the same hostname and port number from SQL Developer? Should you be using the service name for your connection rather than the SID (radio button selection in the SQL Developer connection panel)? Are you able to connect from SQL\*Plus from the same PC you're trying to run SQL Developer on, or only locally on the DB server machine? Is the listener on an external IP, or only on localhost?

Comment: go into preferences, database, advanced. there's an option there to specify where your TNSNames file is. point it to the one that SQL*Plus is using. now change your connection from Direct to TNS. OR, open your tnsnames file, and get the servername/IP, SID/Service, and Port# that's defined for the 'XE' connection

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the following scenario:
You use an ssh client such as Bitvise to forward between local ports and remote ones.
You want to sql developer to connect to an existing db where you already have the db and the user credentials. And you also have SSH access to the machine that hosts the Oracle DB.

SSH into the remote DB and switch to the DB user.
Check the Listener port:

```
cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora
```

This returns among other things a line like:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <servername>)(PORT = 1521))
```

Now you know your target port is `1521`.

Check the Oracle SID:

```
echo $ORACLE_SID
```

You'll need this later on.

Forward a local port of your choice to the remote one in Bitvise along the lines of:

```
Listen Interface    List. Port  Destination Host    Dest. Port  Comment
127.0.0.1           11521       <servername>        1521        Oracle-DB
```

Fire up Oracle SQL Developer

Click the green + sign - up pops the new connection menu.

```
Connection Name:    XYZ_Oracle
Username:           Oracle_db_username
Password:           pwd_for_db_username

Connection type:    Basic
Role:               Default
Hostname:           127.0.0.1
Port:               11521 (the forwarded port)
SID:                the ID of the particular DB you want to access aka db name
```

Press `Test`

Press `Connect`

### Errors you may get:

Invalid username/password - Make sure you use the uname/pwd that you use to access the DB with slqplus.

String index out of range - Are you trying to connect on a wrong port? Maybe 22? Check the listening port / forwarding port

Listener refused the connection. Unknown SID. - Make sure you are using the right system ID.